# Involution of $L^1$ reversing composition order

Tags: functional-analysis, involutions

Let $L^1_{\mu}$ be a separable $L^1$ space for a Borel measure $\mu$.  Does there exists a (continuous) involution $i$ on $L^1_{\mu}$, such that
$$
i(f \circ g) = g\circ f;
$$
whenever composition is well-defined?

Comment: For which kind of functions $f,g$ should this hold?

Comment: I just need them to be part of some (proper) dense subspace...

Comment: dense subspace of what?

Comment: of $L^1_{\mu}$ (on which composition is well-defined)

Comment: If $\mathrm{id}\in L^1_\mu$, then $i(f)=i(\mathrm{id}\circ f)=f\circ\mathrm{id}=f$, but $f\circ g=g\circ f$ certainly does not hold for all $f,g$.